# Android - Dynamic module(.so) needs to be production signed

Tags: android, shared-libraries, digital-signature, shared-objects, hexagon-dsp

As i understand this from Hexagon DSP document:

> To enable a .so to be successfully deployed on production devices
>   across a large number of OEM devices, the dynamic module needs to be
>   production signed by the OEM. ISVs are encouraged to work with their
>   OEM POCs to have the modules production signed for OEM devices.

So, is there any way i can get my .so(s) to work on production device (OnePlus 3T running OxygenOS originally)?

I have tried to root the device by compiling LineageOS and installing it. So this gives be 'adb root' access but still i get following `dlopen` error:

```
01-14 19:25:36.211 15243 15243 E adsprpc : vendor/qcom/proprietary/adsprpc/src/fastrpc_apps_user.c:433::error: -5: 0 == (nErr = dlerr)
01-14 19:25:36.212 15243 15243 D adsprpc : vendor/qcom/proprietary/adsprpc/src/fastrpc_apps_user.c:437: dlopen error: calculator signature verify start failed for libcalculator_skel.so
```

Any idea how can i fix this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I talked to Qualcomm India and US with concerned person (I made sure they are the stakeholders and can give authentic information), and found that it is not possible unless you buy license from them, this is not even possible for any lean startup(with limited funds). The other option is to get into their investor program (Qualcomm Ventures).

So if you are planning to buy [Intrinsyc](https://www.intrinsyc.com/) board for prototyping and thinking that later you will run the same DSP software on production, BIG CAUTION!!! This is not possible unless you solve the above signature problem.

In my opinion, stay away from license TRAP!

Answer (score 1):

What software is allowed to on Qualcomm DSPs is currently controlled by the device's OEM.  If you want something to run on the DSP you must work directly with the OEM.

Not all devices require signing, there are drone and other non-phone devices that may run unsigned modules.