# How do I give Android apps access to the Hexagon DSP

Tags: android, android-source, hexagon-dsp

I'm trying to run some Android apps of mine on the Hexagon DSP on a Google Pixel. However, access to the DSP is being restricted. Using the AOSP source is it possible to modify the policy of whether Android programs can run on the Hexagon DSP? Using, e.g., SEL policies? The Android docs state that some OEMs (in particular for the Pixel) restrict access to the Hexagon DSP. Is this something decided in the proprietary binaries or in some configurations in AOSP?

Comment: See https://stackoverflow.com/a/44519529/489590 for a related answer

Comment: Yea I came across that post before. The accepted answer states "So if you are planning to buy Intrinsyc board for prototyping and thinking that later you will run the same DSP software on production, BIG CAUTION!!! This is not possible unless". Does a rooted Pixel phone with custom AOSP count as "production"? Where is this restriction enforced?

Comment: To add to that, the reason why I didn't lose hope yet is because some applications ARE able to utilize the Hexagon DSP (e.g., when I run from the command line). So my suspicion is the restriction is buried somewhere in the AOSP tree.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you should try this https://github.com/geohot/freethedsp if your still interested. It should let you bypass the signature checks, Definitely read the source for more info, you'll have to edit the addresses in the code for the patch to work on your specific phone, but it should work. also thank you to geohot!

forgot to mention, i think i read somewhere that selinux policys on the newer versions of android only let certain apps access dsp remote procedure calls but you can fix that if your root or using AOSP.

Answer (score 1):

If the application is signed by device manufacturer, only then this can be accessed on a production device. You may change AOSP code and bypass  the same but if your intention is to distribute the application, it might not be a good idea.